# Как смонтировать SD карту в ext4 на Android?

Tags: android, linux, sd

Имеется SD карта (32гб). Нужно смонтировать её в телефон, подключаю через OTG. Да только вот одна проблема: Android даже родной **ext4** в упор не видит, предлагает форматировать SD карту в **FAT32** (а это меня, в свою очередь, крайне не устраивает). Пробую форматировать **в ext4** (с ПК). Но SD не видно даже в */dev/block* (!)

```
root@termux:~# ls /dev/block | grep sda
sda
root@termux:~# mkfs.ext4 /dev/block/sda
Found msdos partition table on /dev/block/sda.
Proceed anyway?(y/N)y
```

Но, даже после этого карта в упор не хотела монтироваться. Решил поменять fstab, а именно: поменять формат монтирования с vfat на ext4. Однако, после редактирования ловлю бутлуп. А что самое худшее - fstab был в разделе /vendor, да и вообще я не делал бэкапа /vendor! Пришлось вообще выносить строку, указывающую на монтирование внешнего девайса. Так что вопрос: как заставить Android монтировать ext4 (впрочем, подойдёт любой ext-формат, но ни в коем случае не FAT, за исключением exFAT. Подойдёт и NTFS/f2fs)

Comment: проблему с видимостью карты в */dev/block* я решил. Но как её смонтировать, остаётся загадкой...

Comment: А вы прямо без разделов карту хотите сделать? Может стоит попробовать таблицу разделов создать, и не затирать её потом форматированием диска-как-партиции?

Comment: я там пробовал создавать через ```busybox fdisk```. После создания вроде бы даже монтирует, но после переподключения все идёт на круги своя

Comment: Так вам смонтировать или разметить карту надо? Если первое, то почему вы пытаетесь делать это на телефоне? Сделайте на нормальном компьютере, проверьте, что всё работает.

Comment: мне её именно смонтировать надо. Но телефон не видит разделы на ней (потому что их, похоже, нету), из-за чего её приходится размечать.

Comment: Я имел в виду разметку. Зачем вы размечаете на телефоне? Начните с компьютера, разберитесь с разметкой и таблицами разделов, посмотрите, что всё работает. Потом уже на телефоне. (Мне почему-то кажется, что вы не видите разницу между /dev/sda и, например, /dev/sda1, а она весьма существенна)

Comment: `mkfs.ext4 /dev/block/sda` или как кирпичнуть аппарат за 3 секунды)

Comment: эм, телефон вообще-то ```/dev/block/mmcblk0```

Answer (score 0):

Если есть другой смартфон (желательно такой же версии Android) попробуй в него вставить SD карту и уже с помощью него отформатируй, и потом используй в том котором хотел. Мне это помогло когда один телефон не видел SD карту

P.S. Убедись что телефон поддерживает SD карты такого объема памяти

Comment: Георгий, да вот беда: ещё в fstab прописано форматирование SD карточки: ```/device/block/platform/soc/a800000.usb/*   /mnt/media_rw   vfat    rw,nodev,nosuid``` (уже забыл, какая конкретно там была строка)

Comment: а FAT (искл exFAT) мне не нужен, мягко говоря

Comment: что интересно - я могу к своему телефону подключить другой телефон...